# mvcSiteMapNode with a non-specific attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I have a page which can be reached through two different paths. The way to tell which route it took is by looking at the url parameteres. In one case, the url parameter would be `?guid=...` and other will be `?mode=...`

Here is a sample sitemap file:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="home" controller="my_controller" action="first_Action">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" guid="[what to put here?]" ></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>

<mvcSiteMapNode title="List page" controller="my_controller" action="second_Action">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" mode="[what to put here?]"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Various examples on the internet have the attributes set to actual values but in my case, the url parameters `guid` and `mode` can be variable.

What do i have to put in `guid` or `mode` to make the sitemap map correctly? or do i have to use `preservedRouteParameters` or something else

Comment: if the params are variables why do you put them in the sitemap?

Comment: What happens if you leave it blank like this guid="" and mode ="" in both the nodes. Can you check? It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map a dynamic page like you describe - the input of `guid` and/or `mode` will likely change based on what content the user is requesting. What it looks like you want, is to have every valid variant of your `Details` page in the sitemap. However, there's no way for the site map provider to know what the valid values of `guid` and/or `mode` actually are, unless you tell it *exactly* what the valid values are.

You can tell it by being explicit:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="home" controller="my_controller" action="first_Action">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" guid="1" ></mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" guid="2" ></mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" guid="3" ></mvcSiteMapNode>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="my_other_controller" action="index" guid="4" ></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

If you don't believe me, this is also described in the examples in the exact same way on the documentation page for the site map provider, here: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML

If you don't fancy that, then you need to look at a manual, do-it-yourself solution by registering custom routes. Such as handling `/sitemap.xml` etc.